# Complex multiplication identity

Tags: math

From my EM theory book:

[image: Problem]

[image: Solution]

I have the solution for this problem, but I don't even understand the first step. How does \$V = r + jx \implies v(t) = rcos(wt) - xsin(wt) \$??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula to convert from the phasor representation \$V=r+jx\$ to its time-domain equivalent is this:

\$
V(t) = Re\{V \, e^{\,j\omega t}\}
\$

Using the complex identity:

\$
e^{\,j\omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + j\,\sin(\omega t)
\$

You obtain:

\begin{align*}
V(t) &= Re\{V \, e^{\,j\omega t}\} 
 = Re\{ (r+jx) \cdot [\cos(\omega t) + j\,\sin(\omega t)] \} = \\[1em]
 &= Re\{ r \cos(\omega t) - x \sin(\omega t) + j[...] \} = \\[1 em]
 &= r \cos(\omega t) - x \sin(\omega t)
\end{align*}